# How to automatically select the organic group audience when adding content?

Tags: organic-groups, 7

How can I setup a link on a group page to add content that automatically selects the group audience as the referred group?

For instance:

I'm a member of the group "Puppy Kittens" and I'm logged in to that group page (node/12) and I have links on that page to "Add Post". The link "Add Post" opens up and allows me to add a post for my group without me having to select my group.

Comment: do you use panels ?

Comment: I ended up using Entity reference prepopulate. I setup the group audience field in my group content nodes with this module and then added it to a Page. This gave me the links that I wanted. OG Extras OG Content Links isn't working for me for some reason. Thanks all!

Comment: what OG version are you using ? 7.2 or 7.1 ?

Comment: I'm using OG version 7.2.

Comment: Have a look at entity reference prepopulate.

Answer (score 0):

[OG group extras](http://drupal.org/project/og_extras)

> Extra functions, blocks, and views for Organic Groups 7.2. In
>   particular, this module adds views and blocks needed by sites that are
>   not using Panels.

This only works on OG 7.2 but not on OG 7.1. If you are using OG 7.1, you can use [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and add a create group content panel to the node page.